# How to get string after every slash?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get everything before the / character in a string. Some example strings are below.

```
1/2/3/4/5/7/8/19/20/26/28/32/38/40/41
```

I want the string to be added into comboBox :

```
1
2
3
4
5
7
8
19
20
26
28
32
38
40
41
```

Comment: Did you try splitting by `/`?

Comment: `someString.Split("/")` ?

Comment: This question made me cry a little

Comment: Any code to show? Otherwise your question may be considered _too broad_. [ask]

Comment: Which language you are using? Most of the languages have string split functions, just google it and you will find it easy to use

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Split()` function:

```
myString.Split("/")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string sayi =  "1/2/3/4/5/7/8/19/20/26/28/32/38/40/41";

var result=sayi.Split('/');

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```